# Which maven2 artifacts are necessary to build a WS with CXF and Spring?

Tags: maven-2, cxf, spring-3

I'm trying to build a WS with Spring 3.0 and CXF. I'm following the steps of this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pojo-springcxf/
But in that article, the authors assume that you have cxf installed. I'd like to embed CXF in my .war.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, just depend on cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws  and cxf-rt-transport-http.   Pretty much the rest of the stuff needed would be pulled in transitively from those.  (might not even need cxf-rt-transport-http)  That would cover 90% of the usecases.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

For more advanced things like WS-Security and WS-RM and JAX-RS, you would need to add additional modules.