# How to build a WS with CXF and Spring?

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I'm trying to build a WS with CXF. I'm following this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pojo-springcxf/
But I have 2 questions:

1) [Which maven2 artifacts are necessary to build a WS with CXF and Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969268/which-maven2-artifacts-are-necessary-to-build-a-ws-with-cxf-and-spring)

2) I'm getting this error: FileNotFound: META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml. I don't know where this file is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace for your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have proper cxf dependencies declared.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml is in cxf-rt-core-2.2.5.jar which is one of the transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml is in cxf-2.3.0.jar
You will need these jars to run cxf webservices

```
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.2.jar
cxf-2.3.0.jar
cxf-manifest.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.1.1.jar
jstl.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
spring-aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
standard.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.5.9.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
xmlsec-1.4.3.jar
```