# How to get CXF jars with Ivy

Tags: cxf, ivy, dependency-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which maven2 artifacts are necessary to build a WS with CXF and Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969268/which-maven2-artifacts-are-necessary-to-build-a-ws-with-cxf-and-spring)

I am using an `ivy.xml` file to get dependencies I need. So to get some dependencies, I write e.g.

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-entitymanager" rev="3.6.6.Final">
    <artifact name="hibernate-entitymanager" type="jar" />
</dependency>.
```

When searching [the Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org) for CXF, I found the following Ivy dependency information:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf" rev="2.5.2" >
    <artifact name="cxf" type="pom" />
</dependency>
```

That dependency has `pom` instead of `jar` for type. How can I get jars for CXF with Ivy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[apache-cxf](/questions/tagged/apache-cxf) is split into [several](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/) JARs. I don't know [ivy](/questions/tagged/ivy) but you probably need to import them separately, for example:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf" rev="2.5.2"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws" rev="2.5.2"/>
```

Comment: I am guessing my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969268/which-maven2-artifacts-are-necessary-to-build-a-ws-with-cxf-and-spring